# How can I use transform matrices without using shaders with the OpenGL SuperBible in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transform

I am well versed in C++, but fairly new to openGL and the OpenGL SuperBible.  I would like to take a projection matrix that the prior developer used in a shader and apply the matrix without a shader.  For example, I would like to take the following (only the relevant code is posted):

```
GLShaderManager shaderManager;
// Zoom and shade
shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix(), vGreen);
```

and use it to adjust the zoom without applying the shader (where ???? is the function I am looking for):

```
// Adjust the zoom without applying a shader
????(viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix());
```

My question is, what function(s) could I use to do this?  Note that the matrix in viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix() is already set up, and I am trying to avoid having to recode this whole functionality.  I am looking for a function that will just apply the matrix and not interfere with color.

Clarification:
The object I am drawing can have over 1 million polygons, and changes color.  I am simply looking for a function that goes in place of ????.

Comment: [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)?

Comment: I suspect it should really be called scaling vs. zoom.  What I want to do is to be able to view my flat projection at different ranges (sort of like zooming in and out in Google maps).  The portion in viewFrustrum.GetProjectionMatrix() appears to handle this correctly, except I don't want the shader to be applied.  I just want to preserve the "zoom" functionality.

Comment: @user1095108 Zoom is a function of focal length / field of view in a perspective projection, it is not the same thing as scale, though that is effectively what it does based on distance.

Comment: @genpfault I did some searching on GLM, and it appears to be a library.  Would you happen to know the particular function within that library I could use, or preferably a basic opengl command to apply a transform matrix?

Comment: "Applying" a transformation matrix is as simple as multiplying by it.

Comment: @ECrownofFire What would I multiply the matrix by?  The way it is currently implemented, I invoke the shader, then I draw the polygons.  The problem I have is that whatever colors I specify for the polygons, they get "overwritten" by the color specified in the shader (although zooming is handled correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not quite what I was looking for, I did finally come across a solution that works with my code.  I was able to play around with the factors that were used to set up the projection matrix, and then do the following:

```
glPushMatrix(); //Save the current matrix state

// ... Do calculations to convert from orthographic to scaling factors (basically 1/x)

glScaled(x,y,1.0); // Scale, increasing by a factor of x and y

// ... Do my drawing

glPopMatrix(); // Revert to the previous matrix state (before zooming)
```

If someone can still find a function to take the place of ???? in my original question, I will probably come back and accept it.  Thank you all for your help, and assistance in finding good opengl resources.

Comment: I think you're going extremely backwards about this. Trivial shaders take a few lines each, and once you have them, you can add reasonable matrix handling yourself with the help of GLM. Right now you're left with pile of code that's old, deprecated, slow, and eventually will have to be thrown out and rewritten anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Do you know how to make a shader not apply color?  The problem I am running in to with shaders is that it "overwrites" the colors I assign to my polygons with whatever is in vGreen.  Keep in mind I am new to openGL and the openGLSuperBible, so I may be missing something trivial.

Comment: Fragment shader will *always* compute a fragment color, but you can change what it would be, for example by setting an uniform variable or by adding another vertex attribute and passing it from vertex shader.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thank you for your quick response!  I am drawing an object that has potentially over 1 million polygons, each potentially a different color, and that changes color.  Would I need to call the shader over a million times (e.g. in my loop that draws the object), passing in polygon x's color each time?

Comment: No, in that case use the latter approach; create another buffer with color data for each vertex, or interleave color data with vertex positions. Pass them as two separate attributes to vertex shader, and simply copy them over to fragment shader to determine final color. There are numerous examples over the web how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the configuration of the matrices in OpenGL, such as  how many rows and columns they have and whether they are row or column major. This can be gleaned from many places, including:

1. The [official OpenGL specs](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl42-quick-reference-card.pdf).
2. Some [tutorial on the subject](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/matrices_can_be_your_friends.html)
3. From  the sources of some of the many OpenGL compatible matrix math libraries out there.

In fact most 3D engines based on OpenGL will have some rudimentary form of matrix support that is compatible. It might actually be better to just use one of those libraries.

@genpfault suggested [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net) which looks promising.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  This at least gives me some decent resources to look at, and I have had difficulty finding good opengl resources online.

Answer (score 1):

You need No shader for that. As Stated on OpenGl Documentation 
(http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations)

"A simple method for zooming is to use a uniform scale on the ModelView matrix. However, this often results in clipping by the zNear and zFar clipping planes if the model is scaled too large.

A better method is to restrict the width and height of the view volume in the Projection matrix."

```
static float zoomFactor; /* Global, if you want. Modified by user input..*/
/* A routine for setting the projection matrix. May be called from a resize
  event handler in a typical application. Takes integer width and height 
  dimensions of the drawing area. Creates a projection matrix with correct
  aspect ratio and zoom factor. */
void setProjectionMatrix (int width, int height)
{
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective (50.0*zoomFactor, (float)width/(float)height, zNear, zFar);
  /* ...Where 'zNear' and 'zFar' are up to you to fill in. */
}
```

Edited:

There is no need for an extra "apply matrix function".

"gluPerspective specifies a viewing frustum into the world coordinate system...  The matrix generated by gluPerspective() is multipled by the current matrix, just as if glMultMatrix() were called with the generated matrix. To load the perspective matrix onto the current matrix stack instead, precede the call to gluPerspective() with a call to glLoadIdentity()

From: http://code.nabla.net/doc/OpenGL/api/OpenGL/man/gluPerspective.html

Comment: I think this question is about the programmable pipeline OpenGL API, not the fixed pipeline.

Comment: OP says, without applying the shader.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion.  What I am looking for is the function to apply the transformation specified by the matrix, without using the shader.  The problem I am having is that all the polygons turn out the color specified in the shader (even though I specify different colors).  I want to just apply the matrix effect without the shader (or if there is a "null" shader that keeps the original colors, that may work too).  This may be useful still.  Mainly I am looking for the function that goes in place of ???? above.

Comment: I've extended the answer to include doc of method. But You can also take a look on GLTools (https://github.com/HazimGazov/GLTools/blob/master/src/math3d.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Let me try.

Supposition:

- Your frustum is simmetrical, i.e., top = -botton and left = -right (those are the values you have used to specify the frustrum matrix)

To achieve zoom effects, let's say, by factor f, just multiply the diagonal matrix by this factor (only for the two first row), i.e.

```
  m = viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix();
  m[0][0] = m[0][0] * f;
  m[1][1] = m[0][0] * f;

  shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, m, vGreen);
```

which, essentially is apply a scale matrix to it.

But, I believe is easier to change viewFrustum via is function parameter, or better yet, by using perspective matrix.

And yes, you have to pass this matrix to the shaders, there no way to change it only in CPU

**Another solution:**

Modify your vertex shader, by creating a new uniform variable, let's say: scale

In gl_position attribution, change it to be something like this:

```
gl_Position = scale * YOUR_MATRIX * points;
```

Now, in CPU, attribute your scale matrix to this uniform, using something like this:

```
m = scale(f, f, 1);
`pass m to vertex uniform shader`
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  In passing the matrix to the shader, is there any way to not have the shader modify the color?  The problem I am having in using the shader is that it is making all the polygons white (although the prior developer incorrectly used vGreen to specify white).  I want the polygons to be the color I specify, and don't want the shader to impact the color.  If there is a way to pass the shader a "null" color that does not impact the color of the polygons, that would work too.

Comment: It depends how you have implemented your shaders. Specifing those matrixes only usually change the points positions, not its color.